# Java Ошибка java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

Я в общем склеил всю музыку, которую хотел сделать фоновой, и вышло 315мб. Закинул в проект, и попытался с помощью запустить. Но не вышло( Код метода для проигрывания музыки:

```
public static void play(URL url)
{
    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url));
    clip.start(); 
}
```

Как это исправить? Пробовал увлеичить память, но мне ошибку выбивало, то ли памяти мало, то ли ещё что-то. Всего на компе 2гб ОЗУ.

Answer (score 14):

Попробуйте увеличить размер хипа для jvm.
Для этого в аргументах jvm укажите:

```
java -Xmx1024m -Xms256m
```

Параметр Xmx указывает максимальный размер занимаемый хипом, а Xms — начальный размер выделенный под хип.

Если используете IntelliJ  Idea, то сделать это можно так: выбираете конфигурацию запуска и в поле VM Options прописываете данную строчку (`-Xmx1024m -Xms256m` без `java`).

В Eclipse: Run -> Run configuration -> вкладка arguments -> VM arguments

Comment: Не получилось :( И у меня Eclipse.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
 at Game.Main.play(Main.java:128)
 at Game.Main.<init>(Main.java:55)
 at Game.Main.main(Main.java:79)

Comment: Нашли как в eclipse это сделать (указал в ответе)? Можете до 2 Гб попробовать увеличить. Дело должно быть в этих опциях

Comment: Да, нашёл. Ставил максимально, но не помогло( Я пробовал вместо wav запускать mp3, там памяти меньше нужно. Пробовал различные библиотеки, но всё было неудачно

Comment: Попробуйте проверить точно ли все в логике приложения или музыку как-нибудь пожмите.

Comment: какие ещё форматы аудио поддерживает стандартная библиотека джава?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понел у вас музыка хранится в оперативке. П.с никто не хранит музыку в оперативке, там всегда были буферы размером(сколько указано в формате вашего файла, например битрейт в 128 кб). Я думаю вам не получится реализовать это с помощью Clip, или занесите вашу музыку в файл чтоли.

Comment: И п.с в mp3 памяти куда больше и cpu куда больше, все конвертится в wav.!!!!

Comment: можно по-подробнее?( Всмысле в оперативке? Как её ещё хранить?

Comment: Это зависит от вашей идеи. Загружать весь mp3 файл в оперативку это кхе, а еще клеить в оперативке это еще кхее. А если mp3 БУДЕТ ГИГА 3???? И ИЗ НЕГО WAV НА гигов 6. В оперативку.............. реализация зависит от вас.

Comment: так я не понял, как это, в оперативку))

Comment: Вижу еще рано вам делать такие приложения.

Comment: Я 2д игрушку через JFrame и Graphics делаю, ничего особенного)

Comment: Этого очень мало...