# Почему длина константы может быть только 65534

Tags: java, строки

Выходит ошибка компиляции при попытке скомпилировать

```
String s = "65535 символов на одну больше чем 2 в степени 16"
```

а вот 65534 символа компилирует, почему то в пуле строк не может содержаться строк больше двух байтов? плюс логично то что максимальный размер строки может быть только Integer.MAX_VALUE, потому что string.length() возвращает int, но что то при попытке запустить

```
    while (true) {//делал такое и со String, сути и ошибки не меняются
        stringBuilder.append(stringBuilder);
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.length());
    }
```

выдает ошибку

```
536829952
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Даже близко не подойдя к максимальному значению int.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method

Comment: У Вас тут два вопроса которые на самом деле имеют между собой очень мало общего: первый относится к компиляции, второй — к исполнению. На Stack Overflow не принято задавать несколько вопросов в одном. Попробуйте задать их по-одному.

Comment: Вопрос похожий (но не совсем) на первую часть Вашего: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661454/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83

Comment: Вопрос похожий на вторую часть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537294/java-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Comment: @default-locale  на самом деле можно найти больше вопросов, если так смотреть)

Comment: @default-locale я писал -Xmx4096m -Xms1500m но не помогает, смотрю диспетчер задач выдает, он не занимает ни 2 гигабайта ни тем более больше и все равно такая же ошибка

Comment: @AlexanderBelov Попробуйте больше. Для построения гигантской строки используются промежуточные объекты. Например, `StringBuilder` использует внутренние массивы. В любом случае скорее всего Вы упретесь в другую ошибку: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have#41024966

Comment: да, помогло, увеличил до 10 гигов